# persistent connections will avoid max_user_connections?

Tags: php, mysql

I have one website and 1 user to login to mysql.

Mysql has a 25 limit connection. many times I have about 100 users online and it give me an error:

> User s already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections

persistent connections may help me to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have hosted this on any shared hosting provider,persistent connections can cause max_user_connections reach out.

If Max_user_connections is set to 25 means 25 concurrent connections "per mysql user" limit so the User S has reached his limit of 25 concurrent connections.

tips that prevent this situation:

**1) Use of mysql_connect()**

The connection to the server will be closed as soon as the execution of the script ends.

**2) Use of mysql_close()**

This will close the connection explicitly.

**3) Prevent use of mysql_pconnect()**

The connection will remain open for future use. mysql_close() will not close links established by mysql_pconnect.